# How to pass a dictionary with more arguments into a proc in tcl?

Tags: tcl

```
proc test {a b c } {
       puts $a
       puts $b
       puts $c
}
set test_dict [dict create a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5]
```

Now I want to pass dict into test like this:

```
test $test_dict
```

How to make `test` only selects three elements in the dict with the same name of its parameters (the keys). The expected output should be:

```
2
3
4
```

Because it selects `a b c` in the dictionary but not `d`. How can I do this? I saw some code does like this but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use `dict get`:

```
proc test {test_dic} {
  puts [dict get $test_dic a]
  puts [dict get $test_dic b]
  puts [dict get $test_dic c]
}

set test_dict [dict create a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5]
test $test_dict
```

Edit:
Another variant would be to use `dict with`:

```
proc test {test_dic} {
  dict with test_dic {
    puts $a
    puts $b
    puts $c
  }
}

set test_dict [dict create a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5]
test $test_dict
```

But `test` gets still a list.

Comment: I saw the argument list contains individual elements, not a list, but at calling time, only a single dictionary is passed into the function. I think the author used some techniques to expand the dictionary when it is passed into the argument list.

Comment: Or `dict with test_dict {test $a $b $c}` (but that pollutes the caller).

Comment: Edited: `test_dic` to become `test_dict`